# ul list not rendering correctly in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, html-lists, html-rendering

When my list shows, the first element of my list is at the correct place, but starting from the 2nd one till the end, they all appear under the bullet instead of besides it :/

if you need to see the code go to http://www.nsworld.org/development (click on the USA)

I'm trying to find a fix for this problem, it only appear in IE8, all the other browsers everything shows perfectly.

Comment: Please post the code or a small, simple, working example. This is to guard against link rot.

Comment: if you read below the question, you will see the code, also the answer was to put all the code that was creating my list inside my javascript file instead of leaving it on the html page, by doing this there was no more conflict about reading the code and the concatenation of the strings i wanted to shows when a user clicked a country

Comment: So what happens when that link no longer works?

Comment: what link are your refering to?

Comment: http://www.nsworld.org/development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your anchor tags (as wellas your list items) - they're only being opened, but never closed:

```
"<li>"+"<a href='http://nsworld.org/'>"+"Foo"+""+""+"<br />"+"<br />"+
```

This code, in general, needs to be greatly re-worked. There's a lot of unnecessary concatenation going on, which destroys the legibility of this line (as well as those surrounding it).

Additionally,

There are a few things I would suggest. First would be that you start using a Standards `doctype`, such as `<!DOCTYPE html>` so that you're getting more consistent behavior across various browsers, and versions.

Secondly would be to close your tags. I noticed that these list items aren't being closed, and as such the task is left to the browser to determine how subsequent list items ought to be formatted. While this isn't *invalid*, it is definitely not a practice I would encourage.

Lastly would be to avoid verbose string concatenation in JavaScript, such as the following:

```
 switch (code) {
    case "us":
x="<ul>"+
"<li>"+"<a href='http://nsworld.org/findings/How-does-it-all-Fit-Together/Capacities#!prettyPhoto[examples2]/2/'>"+"Envision Charlotte"+""+""+"<br />"+"<br />"+
"<li><a href='http://nsworld.org/findings/Building-New-Capacities-Emergence/Innovative-Societies#!prettyPhoto[examples2]/2/'>"+"US Open Government Initiative"+""+
"<li>"+"<a href='http://nsworld.org/findings/Building-New-Capacities-Emergence/Innovative-Societies#!prettyPhoto[examples2]/3/'>"+"Unreasonable Institute"+""+""+
"<li>"+"<a href='http://nsworld.org/findings/Building-New-Capacities-Emergence/Innovative-Societies#!prettyPhoto[examples2]/4/'>"+"FailFaire"+""+""+
"<li>"+"<a href='http://nsworld.org/findings/Building-New-Capacities-Emergence/Emergent-Solutions#!prettyPhoto[examples]/1/'>"+"Ushahidi-Haiti"+""+""+
"<li>"+"<a href='http://nsworld.org/findings/Building-New-Capacities-Emergence/Public-Organizations-as-Experimentation-Platforms#!prettyPhoto[examples2]/3/'>"+"Social Innovation Fund"+""+""+
"<li>"+"<a href='http://nsworld.org/findings/Building-New-Capacities-Resilience/Adaptive-Capacity#!prettyPhoto[examples2]/1/'>"+"Community and Regional Resiliency Institute (CARRI)"+""+""+
"<li>"+"<a href='http://nsworld.org/articles/community-resilience-taking-tangible-steps-towards-achieving-societal-resilience'>"+"Community Resilience: Taking Tangible Steps Towards Achieving Societal Resilience"+""+""+
"<li>"+"<a href='http://nsworld.org/discoveries/nurse-family-partnership-co-produces-results-us'>"+"Nurse-Family Partnership Co-Produces Results in the U.S."+""+""+
""
        break;
```

You could instead have these lists preloaded, pulled down asynchronously, or have the data populated in a JavaScript object of some sort. As you can see, massive amounts of string concatenation make code very unreadable, and offer many more opportunities for mistakes.

Comment: fi know i should of preloaded a list with all the links i needed in my list that i call when i click on the countries, but i couldn't figure it out and ask here how to do it by XML and got no answers, thats why i came up with this "solution" of putting verbose string concatenation in javascript.

Comment: @KaylanBrunet I understand; it is sometimes tough to get the answers we're looking for. First step would be to avoid unnecessary concatenation, resulting is slightly easier to read code. Notice for example in your code above that you at times have `"<li>"+"<a` and at times have `"<li><a` - the latter is far easier to read. Don't break up strings unless you need to. Hope this helps.

Comment: the "<li<a part was a test to see if taking out some concatenation in my string would help to render correctly my list, didn't change at all :/

Comment: @KaylanBrunet Since you aren't closing your `<a>` tags, IE8 thinks the following `<li>` is supposed to go *inside* of the link. Closing the `<a>` tags should resolve this. Also, close the `<li>` for good measure ;)

Comment: weird, they are all close, all the <a></a> & <li></li>, evrything works fine, but in IE8 the list doesn't render like it should; the second element goes under the bullet instead of beside it

Comment: yes it is, but i only cleaned up the string for the USA, when it will work there i'll fix it for the other countries i need to fix it

Comment: @KaylanBrunet It appears you have not yet closed the tags, or that your site is delivering a cached file. Either way, the list items and anchors are still not closed for the US data. If you have other formatting issues, consider removing the `<br/>` tags you have within there as well.

Comment: So my problem of my UL list not rendering correctly might be caused by the CMS i'm using? and all there CSS files that are linked to the website? That's why i was trying to do a conditional comment in my code to fix the IE8 bug for my list

Comment: @KaylanBrunet Not from what I can tell; from what I see the problem is the JavaScript code. The JavaScript needs to produce `<li><a href=''>Text</a></li>`, but instead is producing `<li><a href=''>Text`, which when repeated, nests each subsequent `li` into the `a` it was following.

Comment: would you have a clue of what would create this behavior in my javascript code?

Comment: @KaylanBrunet In your strings, you're not providing the closing `</a>` or `</li>`. You need to provide those.

Comment: I took all my code that was calling each of my hyperlinks and put it in the same file as my map, and now everything works perfectly in my list in IE8, thank again for all the help you gave me.